# Choosing method to count Stores within concentric buffers using ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, buffer

I have a list of stores, and I have created separate single ring concentric buffers that vary in size (I opted not to use the multiple ring feature). I want to count how many other stores are within each store's buffer. Some stores will clearly overlap. I am using ArcGIS Pro.

I have seen both a "summarize within" suggestion and "spatial join" suggestion with a count option mentioned previously.

Which method is best/simplest for what I want to accomplish?

What are the potential issues with the overlap in this regard?

I don't mind if the total count doesn't equal the number of stores, I just want to make sure each buffer accurately reflects how many other stores are within the buffer.

Comment: Are there any potential overlap issues? As I read your question, it seems ok if Store X is within StoreA, StoreB and StoreC's respective buffers. Right?

Comment: Have you tried either method that you mentioned?  Did you find any issues with your results from any method that you tested?